# How to check if ETH transaction was ever sent

Tags: ethereum, web3js, cryptocurrency

I'm creating a transaction with web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction. I'm then storing that transaction hash, then sending it over the ETH network with web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction

How do I programmatically check if a signed transaction was or wasn't sent yet over the network yet? I'm not interested if it was mined, confirmed or rejected - I just want to check if it was ever sent or not.

Comment: Check the mempool.

Comment: @CherryDT - sorry I don't get it , can you elaborate?

Comment: Google `web3 get transaction from mempool`, too long for me to explain here. (By the way, there is a higher chance for you to get a good answer if you ask on https://ethereum.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

> How do I programmatically check if a signed transaction was or wasn't sent yet over the network yet?

When you create a transaction, you get a transaction hash. With this transaction hash, you can query its status using [eth_getTransactionByHash](https://playground.open-rpc.org/?schemaUrl=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ethereum/eth1.0-apis/assembled-spec/openrpc.json&uiSchema%5BappBar%5D%5Bui:splitView%5D=true&uiSchema%5BappBar%5D%5Bui:input%5D=false&uiSchema%5BappBar%5D%5Bui:examplesDropdown%5D=false) JSON-RPC API.

After you see your transaction being mined in the first block. because the probabilistic nature of proof-of-work network, you need to wait few blocks to ensure that the Ethereum blockchain chain tip does not reorganise. Then you can use `status` flag of the receipt field to determine if the transaction was reverted or not.